# Auto-enumerate Results View

Tags: c#, debugging, collections

So, I've just discovered the wonderful DebuggerDisplay attribute, and have started using it in my code. I've noticed something really quirky about it, though, or perhaps the issue is actually with KeyedCollection.

Without a DebuggerDisplay attribute, I get "Count = x" as the primary display for a KeyedCollection, and that expands to show the elements of the collection. Adding the attribute, however, I get my custom text, as expected, but it now expands to show the various values and properties that I've added to the object itself. That's great, and makes far more sense to me than the collection-->Raw View style that shows up by default. Now, though, the Results View isn't populated by default, it instead has the customary "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable".

How do I get rid of that behaviour? I know the results are safe to enumerate, and would like them to be enumerated automatically. For bonus points, can I have it auto-expand the selection as well?

Comment: There might be a few thing of interest for you here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It would seem that DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute should allow you to do what you want. Just cheat the debugger into thinking the value is a local array and it will show it to you as such. I must say thought: I never tried that myself so maybe it doesn't work at all like I said. But that's worth trying. :)

Comment: I just looked at that, and yeah, with a lot of work, it would get there, but it seems you either have to duplicate your entire class (with whatever fudges you want) or use a lot of Reflection to pull values out of the parent class. Doable, but not terribly worth it for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comments, the closest you can be to what you want is by using the [`DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggertypeproxyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Unfortunately it's a sealed type so you might not be able to make it easy to reuse.